# If $H$ is a normal subgroup and $N\lt H$, does $NhN=h$ or rather some $h'\in H$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

If $H$ is a normal subgroup and $N\lt H$, does $NhN=h$; with $h\in H$? Or rather some $h'\in H$

The relation was a line in a proof, and I was wondering if it was a typo.

Thanks

Comment: There's a typo . This happens iff N={e} because NhN has cardinality the size of N

Comment: Are you sure it says $H$ is a normal subgroup? What is it a normal subgroup of? Everything in the rest of the sentence is happening inside $H$, so it doesn't even make a difference. It would make more sense to say $N$ is normal in $H$, and then something like $NhN=hN=Nh$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$NhN$ has cardinality at least the size of $N$ so this happens iff $N=e$